# Dynamic Config with Key/Value Pairs

Tags: c#, .net, properties, .net-4.5

for one c# application I use app.config to store application configuration variable.

In this application I need to store same key/value that are fixed. 
Also I need to store same key/value "dynamic": my Configuration class where I read this key, read all key which start with a prefix (i.e. Mail) and store it into a HashTable. Then with a public Method a retrieve every configuration key.
Is possibile create into Configuration class, same properties "dynamic" which a specific name. Practically, create at runtime public name (with custom name) from the app.config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question about reading (all) app keys and filter which ones you want, see the example  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx) I would do the `ReadAllSettings()`and filter what you need within you code behind.